# Mirror single window

Tags: screen, window

Is there a way to mirror a single window on my screens?

I want to mirror just one window between two screens, not the whole monitor.

At the moment I am using Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: FYI, you might want to put a bounty on this. It was asked already, but never got an answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150289/mirror-a-single-x-application-on-a-dual-monitor-setup-with-openbox

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `xpra`:

```
xpra start :100 --start-child=PROGRAM --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:10000
xpra attach tcp:localhost:10000
```

As a bonus, it also works remotely – you can attach this window to X (or even Windows and MacOS!) on a different machine. `xpra` is like the console programs `screen` or `tmux` for X11.

Comment: thanks! This looks promising, but I'm not able to make it work. If I use the command you mention I get the following error when I do the `attach`:  `xpra initialization error: unknown format for display name: localhost:10000`. If I change the `attach` command to `xpra attach tcp:localhost:10000` it goes further on, but when I navigate with my browser to `localhost:10000` I get this message `disconnect: invalid packet format, not an xpra client?`. Should I use another program to see the mirrored window?

Comment: @marcosh: the attach syntax was wrong, fixed now - see xpra wiki for more info