# How to close a VPS and leave programs running (using "screen" command)?

Tags: vps

Imagine that I have a program running in a VPS.

I want to close that VPS (maybe turn off the computer) but keep that program running.

I understand I can use "screen" to do so. But I'm unsure how the syntax works. Let's say that the program name is "sessions". How would I use screen to keep sessions operational even when I've exited from the VPS?

I have tried "screen sessions" but when I exit the program, I get "[screen is terminating]"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to close the connection to your VPS (and not the server itself).

Follow those steps after having logged in to the server:

- start screen: `screen`
- start your command: `session`
- detach `screen` from the ssh-session by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>
- now you can terminate your ssh-session
- after logging in again some time later type `screen` to reattach the screen session to the ssh-session

Comment: Here is how to use `tmux` for the same tassk: https://askubuntu.com/a/1027879/566421