# How can I put terminal output on both machines in ssh?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, printing

I am using ssh between two computers, and I was wondering if it is possible to see the terminal output on both computers at the same time. Something like Windows Remote Desktop perhaps.

For example, if I type `ip a` on my own computer while logged into the testing computer via ssh, how can i get the output to show up on the terminal of both my screen as well as the testing computer when the command executes?

I know that it is possible to use redirection to generate a log file on the testing computer, but I want to see if it is possible to either:

1. get that log file to be printed to the screen of the testing computer, and ideally also my computer, without touching the testing computer, only through control from my computer
2. not have to use a log file and just have it be printed to the screen of the testing computer, and ideally also my computer, without touching the testing computer, only through control from my computer

Basically, I'm just asking if it is possible for me to execute a command in ssh while connected to another computer and see the output be displayed to the screen both on my computer (which ssh does) as well as the other computer (which I want to know).

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://www.simplified.guide/ssh/run-gui-application

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have a terminal mirrored onto a second screen in a two-monitor setup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027872/how-to-have-a-terminal-mirrored-onto-a-second-screen-in-a-two-monitor-setup)