# Mirror single application / workspace to an external screen / beamer

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, workspaces, slideshow, projector

When connecting an external monitor / beamer / projector to my laptop, I can choose between two modes: *Join Displays* and *Mirror* (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html)). When teaching, I need a combination of the two modes: I would like to use the *join displays* setup, but mirror one application (even better: one *workspace*).

Ideally, the students would see my mouse as well, just as they would if I would use the *mirror*-mode. (Edit:) I want to switch between the following two situations *seamlessly*:

[image]

---

[image]

(My question is closely related to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/1027872/1385711), the difference being that I would like to mirror any application rather than just a terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/) can solve this problem nicely.

Once installed, you can add your application as a *Source* via *Window Capture PipeWire* or *XComposite*. You then choose *Full Screen Projector (Preview)* and select the external screen / projector / beamer.

OBS does not support sharing a specific workspace (see [here](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/workspaces-on-ubuntu.149276/)). But you can create your own arrangement of applications that you want to share, either by

1. arranging them in a single *scene* (e.g. side by side) or
2. by distributing them over several *scenes*, which layers them on top of each other. Two switch between applications, you simply need to click on the respective *scene*, which brings the application(s) in this scene to up to the top.

Of course, 1 and 2 can be combined. This requires some initial setup, but is very much what I was looking for.

Some additional tips when working in this setup:

- If you add multiple applications to the same *scene*, you must resize their windows accordingly
- I make extensive use of *workspaces*:

  - Bundle applications that are shared in the same scene in a single workspace
  - Use *dynamic workspaces*
  - Enable workspaces on primary display only
  - App switching: include apps from each monitor only

Some Screenshots:

OBS on my internal monitor:

[image]

The OBS preview on my external monitor / beamer / projector

[image]